# How to get element from ArrayList with xml data?

Tags: java

I would like to get searchedProduct name from ArrayList  example in new Product class, how to do it? Everything works correct but only I forgot how to get searchedProduct for example in another class :(

```
public class XMLoader {
private final String XML_PATH = "src\\main\\java\\products.xml";
private List<SearchData> data = new ArrayList<SearchData>();

public XMLoader() throws ParserConfigurationException, IOException, SAXException {
    File inputFile = new File(XML_PATH);
    DocumentBuilderFactory builderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = builderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();

    Document document = documentBuilder.parse(inputFile);
    NodeList nodeList = document.getDocumentElement().getChildNodes();
    for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
        Node node = nodeList.item(i);
        if (node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
            Element element = (Element) node;
            String id = node.getAttributes().getNamedItem("ID").getNodeValue();
            String searchedProduct = element.getElementsByTagName("Category").item(0).getChildNodes().item(0).getNodeValue();
            data.add(new SearchData(id, searchedProduct));
        }
    }
}

public class SearchData {
    private String id;
    private String searchedProduct;


    public SearchData( String id, String searchedProduct) {
        this.searchedProduct = searchedProduct;
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getSearchedProduct() {
        return searchedProduct;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "SearchData{" +
                "id='" + id + '\'' +
                ", searchedProduct='" + searchedProduct + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Comment: what exactly do you mean?

Comment: For example I would like to get access to Id in another class. how to use getter from SearchData class

Comment: ok, but based on what?

Comment: based on data which I read from xml file.

Comment: yes, but you have a list with SearchData. SearchData has an id and a SearchedProduct. Do you mean you have a SearchedProduct, and based on that, you want the id?

Comment: yes, exactly I want to get id

Comment: never mind I solved it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways I can immediately see (I leave it up to you to re-write it to modern Java):

```
public String getIdFromSearchData(String searchedProduct) {
  // iterate over your list
  for ( SearchData element : data ) {
    // compare searchedProduct to the paramater
    if ( searchedProduct.equals(element.getSearchedProduct()) {
      return element.getId();
    }
  }
  // in case nothing found
  return null;
}
```

or, you override the equals method in SearchData to compare the searchedProduct (only)

```
public boolean equals(Object o) {
  // let's assume all checks have been done
  SearchData data = (SearchData)o;
  return data.getSearchedProduct().equals(searchedProduct);
}
```

at which point you can immediately find the element from the list:

```
public String getIdFromSearchData(String searchedProduct) {
    SearchData d = new SeardData(null, searchedProduct);
    if ( data.contains(d) ) {
        d = data.get(data.indexOf(d));
        return d.getId();
    }
    return null;
}
```

A few remarks about this second option:
1. I would strongly recommend against it. One day you might have to compare on the id as well, and at that point, your code will no longer function
2. If you decide to do something like this second way anyway, don't forget to implement the hashCode() method as well.